# Why comes different attribute products in magento

Tags: magento

I have two color attributes under dress category name  Blue & Red.
Under Blue i have 4 products and under Red i have 1 product. but when search Blue i got 5 products both red& blue

Comment: Is there any product with related products with the color red? Then this is correct behaviour

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if attribute frontend property is yes in admin panel -> attributes -> Manage attributes -> select attribute -> "Use in Quick Search"  and "Use in Advanced Search"